# Why does the array from $request contains quotes around the numbers

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have a form in my Laravel application with a multiple select list. When I select multiple users (with id as value) and I echo these in my controller they look like this:

```
array:2 [▼
 0 => "27"
 1 => "28"
]
```

It also saves the array like this in my database. But I already have an array which contains last inserted id's. This one looks like this when I echo it:

```
array:2 [▼
 0 => 27
 1 => 28
]
```

Why is there a difference between these two and how can I make sure that they look like the second example?

This is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $file_ids = [];

    // Handle File Upload
    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

        for ($x = 0; $x < count($request->image); $x++) {
            // Get filename with extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')[$x]->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just extension
            $extension = $request->file('image')[$x]->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $filenameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload image
            $path = $request->file('image')[$x]->storeAs('public/images', $filenameToStore);

            $file = new File;
            $file->name = $filenameToStore;
            $file->path = $path;
            $file->save();

            array_push($file_ids, $file->id);

        }
    }

    $moment = new Moment;
    $moment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $moment->friend_ids = $request->input('friend_ids');
    $moment->file_ids = $file_ids;
    $moment->name = $request->input('name');
    $moment-> location = $request->input('location');
    $moment->date = $request->input('date');
    $moment->save();
}
```

And this is my select list:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-lg-2 offset-lg-5 col-xl-2 offset-lg-5">
   <label for="friend_ids">These friends were there</label>
   <select id="friend_ids" class="custom-select {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="friend_ids[]" required multiple>
    <option value="1">Plorky</option>
    <option value="2">Rizzels</option>
    <option value="3">Crocker</option>
   </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

I already tried to change value="1" to value=1 but that doesn't work. Can anyone explain to me why it works like this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't bother with it. That is how arrays work in PHP. PHP can type cast fine so don't worry, nothing bad will happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_push($friend_ids, (int)$request->input('friend_ids');
```

returned 1 so that didn't work. I used `array_map` with `intval` as callback and now it sets all the strings to integers:

```
$friend_ids = array_map('intval', $friend_ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you post values that are integers with a HTML form, they'll come out in PHP as string values. If you want them as integers in your controller you can cast them:

```
array_push($file_ids, (int)$file->id);
```

Or shorter: `$file_ids[] = (int)$file->id;`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I will mark your answer as answer when I can.

Comment: Indeed, all web requests are sent as strings. This is the reason for things like `XML` , `JSON`  and `content-type`